# Strange reputation/profile issue. Almost 5K rep, and 200+ badges with zero answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15996635/62576) on StackOverflow, and it seemed rather strange to be coming from an almost 5K rep user with 27 gold badges, so I clicked on the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43907/gold).

[image]

It shows a reputation of 4,872, with 575 questions and zero answers. I don't see how a user with zero answers could have earned 27 gold, 96 silver, and 181 bronze badges.

It seems a little strange. Can someone explain how this could be possible?

Comment: This user earned `Famous Question` *24 times*, and `Notable Question` *85 times*. Apparently, he does not need answers :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Actually, he seems to need a *lot* of answers. ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: You're right. I didn't dig deep enough before posting my question. I'll delete it to get rid of the clutter. Thanks for the quick response. :-)

Comment: Classic gold digger who just happened to post some popular (not really good) questions in the past. Nothing wrong here. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yep. My mistake. :-) Thanks for checking. I'll clean this up.

Comment: Too late to clean up, better leave this question be. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: :-) Yeah, I think you're right.

Comment: Why didn't you just look inside the "badges" tab for detail about badges?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Given that rep is usually taken at face value, I would say that this is indeed indicative of something being wrong, somewhere.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment totally agree on this specific case. That user is asking BAD questions, which are now getting downvotes but it's way too little and too late. He won't get question banned in our lifetime and probably just keep using the site as his personal assistant.

Comment: @Chichiray: I've already said (in my first comment above, the 3rd from the top) that it was my mistake for not digging deep enough. How else would you like me to say it?

Comment: I know this guy, has been a help vampire for many years.  First time I saw him was at the MSDN forums.  He's actually been banned several times before at SO.  Last one was a year long.  Questions are basic bike-shed quality.  They are popular at SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43907/) has:

## Earned Gold on:

- 25 Golds on [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question?userid=43907) : *Asked a question with 10,000 views.*
- 1 Gold on  [Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question?userid=43907) : *Question score of 100 or more.*
- 1 Gold on [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic?userid=43907) : *Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days.*

### Earned Silver on:

- 85 Silver on [Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question?userid=43907) : *Asked a question with 2,500 views.*
- 4 Silver on [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question?userid=43907) : *Question score of 25 or more.*

#### Earned Bronze on:

- 160 Bronze on [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=43907) : *Asked a question with 1,000 views.*
- 12 Bronze on [Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question?userid=43907) : *Question score of 10 or more.*

All their reputation comes from questions by up votes and accepting answers. He does not need any answers.